# How to turn my user into root in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, root

Ok so I have a web server on CentOS and I want to run scripts on the webpage but the problem is that some of the scripts require root privileges.

The simple answer I found was to turn my user which in this case is 'mark' into root.

**I know that this could be dangerous.**

Is it possible to transform my user 'mark' into root? or at least to make sure he can run root files?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't use `sudo` or set the `setuid` flag for the specific scripts? https://xkcd.com/149/

Comment: I cant. They are scripts on a CGI python web file. It has already full permission. (chmod 777)

Comment: So, running `sudo chmod u+s file.py`, you could set the `setuid` bit and then run it as `mark` in the context of root user.

Comment: Why don't you just switch into root, run the scripts and then swap back to your usual user? Where's the hardship in that?

Comment: I cant run sudo because in not in the `sudors file` but I did try to run it from `su` and it still did not work.

Comment: Andrew Matthew - I cant switch into root. The script is being called in a AJAX request. So that means the script needs to be able to execute.

Comment: This is the error that gets printed to the console when I call the script in AJAX: `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py  `

Comment: This gets printed in the developer console of your browser? `file://` is a reference to the local file system. So it is trying to run the script on the computer where browser is running, not on your server...

Comment: Not actually. Its getting printed out because its trying to run that file on the server and it dosen't have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do this: Intended for illustration only, an answer to the rhetorical question**

Even though this is dangerous and bad practice, and it is not the solution to your problem, the correct answer is to give your user the 0 uid which can be done with

```
usermod -u 0 mark
```

You might want to add yourself to the group with guid 0, while you are at it.

This is sufficient, as explained in [Does the root account always have UID/GID 0?](https://superuser.com/questions/626843)

**Again, do not to this**

Comment: What makes this that bad?

Comment: @user3932619 I has the same applications as performing all commands as root: No safeguards, no logging, no access control. On top, you now have another user that can be used to break into your system with full privileges. If your web application is hacked, your system is lost. Do only run as root what needs to be run as root, as such use `sudo` or the `setuid` bit on the scripts that need it, only. When performing my suggestion, it is equivalent to running everything as root, which you don't want.

Comment: Ok so how would I be able to run one file as root without using the sudo command because the client dosent have access to the server. I already gave it all the permissions.